# How to set the RecordTypeID

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, contact, record-type

Im trying to set the RecordTypeId of a contact to a certain value if the contact was created by a specific user. Im getting the error:

> A value cannot be stored to RecordTypeId in type Contact.

How can i set the RecordType without getting an error?

```
public void OnBeforeInsert(Contact[] newContacts){

    ID id=[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name='Niki Müller'].ID;
    ID B2C=[Select RecordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE Name='Aamer Ayoob' limit 1].ID;

    for(Contact newContact : newContacts){
        if(newContact.createdById==id){                
            contact.RecordTypeId=B2C;                
            contact.AccountId=contact.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ID B2C=[Select RecordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE Name='Aamer Ayoob' limit 1].ID;` should be changed to `ID B2C=[Select RecordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE Name='Aamer Ayoob' limit 1].RecordTypeId;`

Comment: But then i get the error: Invalid type: RecordTypeId

Answer (score 2):

`ID B2C=[Select RecordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE Name='Aamer Ayoob' limit 1].ID;`

here B2C will give you ContactID and not RecordTypeId.

Check below query to get RecordTypeId for Contact object -

`ID B2C=[SELECT Id, Name, SobjectType FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Contact' AND Name = '<RecordTypeName>' limit 1].ID`

Instead of querying on Contact you can query on RecordType. Please refer below link-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm

Answer (score 1):

Notice you are pulling `Contact.Id` and trying to save it elsewhere to `Contact.RecordTypeId`. These fields reference objects which are not compatible:

```
ID B2C = [Select RecordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE Name='Aamer Ayoob' limit 1].ID;
//                                                   should be RecordTypeId ^^^
... contact.RecordTypeId = B2C;
```

So your `B2C` attribute should instead pull `RecordTypeId` from some other `Contact`.